# printing quickreports with a thermal printer

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, thermal-printer, quickreports

I want to know if thermal printers work with quickreports designed with delphi 7 before I buy one. I have designed a program that generates a receipt like quickreport but I am not sure whether it will work with an e-pos T220 thermal printer before I buy one. Has anyone used thermal printers with quick reports?

Comment: Any printing package will work with any printer that has a Windows printer driver. Does that printer include such a driver? If so, QR will work with it. (And you should be asking this question directly to the authors of QuickReports. It's a vendor support question, and is not really appropriate here. Most software vendors are happy to answer pre-sales inquiries.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pre-sales question that should be addressed to the software vendor. It is not a question of general interest here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, QuickReports supports thermal printers. Our own software supports exactly this and has been from Delphi versions 4 through XE7 (although I personally have not worked with QR).

This includes both barcode/label printers and receipt printers. The general rule of thumb is, if you can print to a printer from Microsoft Word, then you can print to that printer using QuickReports.

If I recall, if you want to use quality font rendering, you have to choose from a limited set of system fonts, as supported by the printer. You can still use other fonts, but the quality of other fonts isn't guaranteed.

You can also print images, although they are in black/white.